# Droidparts InjectView not working

Tags: android, droidparts

I'm trying to use droidParts, specifically the DI part. I'm testing 2 injections, InjectResource and InjectView, but the second one doesn;t seem to be working.

I have a simple default layout with a textView:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

and here's my sample code:

```
import org.droidparts.annotation.inject.InjectResource;
import org.droidparts.annotation.inject.InjectView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends org.droidparts.activity.Activity {

@InjectView(R.id.text1) private TextView txtView;
@InjectResource(R.string.app_name) private String appName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v("testLog", appName);

    txtView.setText("Test");

}   
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

The InjectResource works properly and logs the String, but when it gets to the setText("Test"); line I get a nullPointerException. Is there anything else that needs to be done to use InjectView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content view needs to be set in `preInject()` as `onCreate()` is called right after the injection has been performed. And `Views` can't be found without layout information.

So the code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onPreInject() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    txtView.setText("Test");
}
```